# New order admin email notification is not receving on multiple email address

Tags: sales-order, order-email

I have recently configured new order notification email for two different email ids but i received order notification on only first email but not receiving on second email or more and i am using default magento sender email `sales@example.com` and magento version is `1.9.0.1`. I have also tried using comma like `demo@gmail.com,demo1@gmail.com` but it is not working.
So please let me know how i configured it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Configure order notification to multiple email address.

```
Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Select `Sales Emails` from left panel
```

Enter your provided emails `demo@gmail.com,demo1@gmail.com` with comma separated in `Send order email copy to` text box. Also select `BCC` option from `Send Order Email Copy Method` so that other receiver will not able to see copied email ids.

Note : Their is no space between comma(,) and emails.

Refer to attached screen shot also.

And you should receive your email notificates on provided id.

http://www.amanweb.in/stackexchange/sales-email-configration.jpg

Comment: i have configured same as you suggested but still getting same problem and not receiving any notification on second email.

Comment: check logs `var\log` folder their you should get error related with mailing

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Sales Email -> Order**

Now add comma separated email value to **Send Order Email Copy To** field.

Comment: Thanks a lot..... i changed Send Order Email Copy Method -> to Separate email and now i received all New order notification.

Comment: still i get error, help me pls